# Recommandation / best practise for site to site replication as cold standby with ESXi Cluster

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, replication, vmware-server

I have two ESXI clusters at location A, each consisting of 2 ESXi servers. 1 cluster is in the DMZ and one cluster is in the LAN. Various virtual machines are running on them. In total, there are only 7 virtual machines, including one virtual machine with a MariaDB database (critical).

At the moment, I have a second location B where the identical hardware is operated (identical configuration of the IPS, networks, etc.). Basically a mirrored infrastructure in cold standby. This means that in the event of a failure at location A, we can switch to location B (after adjusting DNS entries). There is currently no requirement for high availability.

The virtual machines are not stored on the local hard disks of the ESXi servers but on a connected SAN. The second location has its own SAN (absolutely identical infrastructure and systems).

At the moment, I install our application software on both sites with every new version and patch the systems at the same time so that the systems are identical. In addition, there is a separate backup of the database server or database. This means that the database is operated in the master-slave, with incremental DB backups every half hour and a weekly full backup, which is written from the storage and also copied to the storage at location B.

During my research I came across the product "VMware Replication", which is included in the licence costs of vSphere. Now I thought it would be a good / sensible option to use this replication to keep the locations synchronised. Question is now, is this too much / too complex? Are there any better options or is this solution perfect for my use case?

Failover is not necessary. In other words, if site A fails and it cannot be resolved promptly, it is switched to site B (after making adjustments to DNS entries for software access).

Comment: Try it. Only you can answer the question. Product recommendations are off topic, you won't get alternatives here.

Comment: vSphere Replication or vSphere Fault Tolerance. I see both being viable solutions. Are their better options? Better than the vendor options? I don't see why you'd want to use an alternative solution when the vendor has two mature, well-proven solutions available to you.

Comment: i don't want alternative software recommendations. but maybe for my scenario there is a better way to do this, like replicate the SAN instead of the virtual maschines. so maybe there are "better" alternatives as best practices from experience